# King of Tokyo: Healing in Tokyo City/Bay

Tags: king-of-tokyo

Can players that are in Tokyo City or Tokyo Bay heal themselves on their turn?

Answer (score 12):

They cannot heal using the "heart" dice, but they can still heal in other ways.

From the rules:

> Being in Tokyo (Tokyo City or
>   Tokyo Bay) has some advantages
>   and disadvantages:
>
> > The Monster in Tokyo
> >     cannot use the
> >     [heart] result on
> >     the dice to heal (but can
> >     heal using cards)

Comment: I would point out that if playing with the power up expansion, although hearts will not provide healing while in Tokyo, they can still trigger getting an evolution card.  Thus, if having rolled a large number of hearts in Tokyo, there is some reason to consider keeping them despite their reduced effect.

Answer (score -2):

They can not heal themselves using hearts in Tokyo City/Bay.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing answer by Gendolkari.